# java- Android Studio [ClassNotFoundException]

Tags: android, android-studio, classnotfoundexception

I got problem when change name `packages` in `android studio`,

first i use some open `source project`, then when i want to change the previous `packages` some of `function` cant be used, the `error message` is `"ClassNotFoundException:yuku.kpri.model.Song"` even thoughni already change `packages` `"yuku"` to `"buna"` and all `packages` that related to `"yuku"` change to `"buna"` and also `packages "yuku.kpri.model.Song"` changes to `"buna.kpri.model.Song"` but the code still run to `yuku.kpri.model.Song`,

**I already try many solution like**

> 1. Close/Unselect `Compact` Empty Middle `Packages` ,Then right click your package and rename it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO0xC.png)
> 2. Clean Project
> 3. Rebuild Project
> 4. change the applicationId [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1iIA.png)

Error Message when try to use the function
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2y6x.png)

Help me to solve this problem, what i miss and my mistake...
im looking for your answer

Comment: Remove all compile  library  and sync and after complete sync add all library again and sync.

Comment: still it not work, thx for help

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is selecting File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart, sometimes it works magic.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a Proguard issue.

Try to set "minifyEnabled false" for both Release & Debug build types in your projects build.gradle file :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

If this works, you should exclude the class in the proguard-ruls.pro file.

Comment: it say "Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on. See http://d.android.com/r/tools/shrink-resources.html for more information." when i do that, whats next?

Comment: still, when i already do your answer still have the same error,